# How to Index Jsonb Field

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, jsonb

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "Id": "4321ecb0-5426-4369-a9ed-851de87c3337",
            "Foo": {
                "Id": "1474bcac-3711-4063-8d25-6491122927f2",
                ...
            },
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a jsonb column C in a database (an example of the data in it is displayed above) and am using C# and Entity Framework core to query this structure thus.  I already have indexes on the text column A and the date column B.

```
"select * from "T" where "A" = 'Some Text' and "C"->'Data' @> '[{"Id":" + theId + "}]' order by "B" desc"
```

In this query, the id that I am searching for is the one within the object Foo.  This query works but is very slow because I do not have any indexes on the id.  I have no idea how to add an index on the id column in the Foo object.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: @jjanes Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the query is written, you might benefit from an index on just a portion of "C".

```
create index on "T" using gin (("C"->'Data'));
```

If you rewrite the query a little, you could use a GIN index on the top level of "C" itself:

```
... AND "C" @> '{"Data":[{"Id":"1474bcac-3711-4063-8d25-6491122927f2"}]}'...
```

but I don't think that has any advantage over the first index for this query, but it might be more flexible and so usable for different queries you might also want to run but that you didn't show.

If the "A" test is selective enough, you might be better off not using any index on the JSONB field at all, and just indexing `on "T" ("A","B")` and letting the JSONB condition get applied as a filter rather than an index.

Answer (score 1):

You should change the condition

```
"C"->'Data' @> '[{"Id":" + theId + "}]'
```

to

```
"C" @> '{"Data": [{"Id":" + theId + "}]}'
```

And use a GIN index on the column:

```
CREATE INDEX ON "T" USING gin ("C");
```